Unable to Type anything in sql developer web not even apex sql command window
I am unable to type anything in sql developer web from oracle cloud console not even apex sql command window in oracle apex, the erorr is

Oracle Apex Cloud sql command window:

{ "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Bad Request", "type": "tag:oracle.com,2020:error/BadRequest", "instance": "tag:oracle.com,2020:ecid/3186ef36b6bf8fd555a0becc6e35f6d3" }
I try to assign role to schema but unfortunately couldn't done.

please contact our oracle cloud support team and open a case
